# How many levels deep is the e4x implementation using square bracket array access notation in AS3?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, e4x

With bracket notation I can access a direct child node by name or attribute using the following code:

Example XML:

```
<item name="item1">
   <categories name="catList">
      <category name="cat1">
   </categories>
</item>
```

Example accessing direct child node:

```
trace(xml["categories"].toString()); // <categories><category/></categories>
```

Example accessing node attribute:

```
trace(xml["@name"].toString()); // item1
```

**Updated**: Is there a way to access a subelement / nested element / nested attribute using ***only*** a single square bracket notation?

For example,

```
trace(xml["categories.category.@name"].toString()); // cat1
```

or

```
trace(xml["categories.@name"]); // catList
```

Comment: you should have a good read of the `XML` class in the official documentation.  everything you'll want to know is there and it's loaded with sample code.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html

Comment: Thanks. I know E4X very well. If this question is answered in that documentation I have not found it.

Comment: @TheDarkIn thanks for the link, it let me to the ECMA e4x spec which was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the square bracket notation is unnecessary if you know the names of the nodes you're accessing.  This should work fine:

```
xml.categories.category.@name.toString();
```

Square bracket notation is used to access properties with a string name.  It is not specifically related to E4X.  The translation of all properties to square bracket notation would be this:

```
xml['categories']['category']['@name']['toString']();
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the code is hardcoded in the Flex SDK as sa = _name == null ? a.toString() : a[_name].toString(); so I'm looking to drill into the node using only a single bracket.

Comment: So this code is some sort of data-binding code?  You may have better luck transforming your data into a format that is more compatible with how this object binds.

Comment: Yes... sort of. I have one string I can pass in but have to access a node deeper than the first level. The code, "a[_name]" leaves me only one option.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

`xml["categories"]["category"][0]["@name"].toString();`

The XML class implements a [Proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html)-like interface. The dynamic properties are dynamically resolved when used, which is why you can invoke properties that aren't defined explicitly on the `XML` class. However, if you are doing some dynamic XML name stuff, and need to use the square bracket notation with strings, then you can definately do that. You just have to wrap each one in its own [ ].

However, there are probably things that you can do with e4x notation that you can't do with [ ]. Namely doing things like:

`xml..@name`

Which will find all name attributes in the entire xml tree. I dont think there is any other way to represent that.

Comment: Thanks. Same as the previous comment, the code is hardcoded in the Flex SDK as sa = _name == null ? a.toString() : a[_name].toString(); so I'm looking to drill into the node using only a single bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments to other answers it seems as though this rather unfortunate use of e4x is deep in the Flex SDK and not something you can alter. In that case I would have to say I'm sorry but you're likely out of luck. Unless of course you own the 'a' variable and can pass that on, in which case you could do the selection beforehand and pass on the appropriate xml fragment to whatever function it is you're calling.

Out of curiosity (and in order to possibly give a better answer,) where in the Flex SDK is this?

---

I had a look at SortField as per your comments and while it does seem cumbersome (and somewhat dangerous) to abuse the internals of the xmlCompare method you should be able to work around it by supplying a custom [compareFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/collections/SortField.html#compareFunction).

Comment: Yep. It's in the SortField xmlCompare function.